# Sum all specified fields in a collection

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using PHP to access a MongoDB collection in which I have recorded purchases of my shop.

Example document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61ff011a5b55479726fe5208"},"monthYear":"2-2022","timestamp":{"$date":"2022-02-05T22:58:34.952Z"},"productIndex":"x","productPriceUSD":10,"customerName":"x","customerID":"x","notes":"x","__v":0}
```

Now I want to add the value of field "productPriceUSD" from all documents in the collection and get a sum at the end.

Maybe someone can help me?

That's my start:
I know, it probably does not make any sense.

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'xxx'
);

$sumtotal = function() use ($client) 
{
    $collection = $client->database->purchases;

    $options = [];

    $filter = [
        ['$group' => [
            '_id' => '$_id',
            'productPriceUSD' => [
                '$sum' => [
                    '$cond' => [ [ '$gt' => [ '$productPriceUSD',  0 ] ], '$productPriceUSD', 0 ],
            ],
        ]],
    ]];

    $result = $collection->aggregate($filter, $options);
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two pipelines you need

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "",
    total: { $sum: "$productPriceUSD" }
   }
 },
 {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      total: "$total"
  }
 }
```

Playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8OTGkK7wLIp